# Invalid token although valid login

Tags: url, token

I'm writing this URL in my browser:

```
https://landfill.bugzilla.org/bugzilla-tip/post_bug.cgi?Bugzilla_login=mymail@hotmail.com&Bugzilla_password=password&product=WorldControl&version=1.0&component=WeatherControl&rep_platform=All&op_sys=All&priority=P2&bug_severity=normal&target_milestone=World%202.0&bug_status=CONFIRMED&assigned_to=somemail@hotmail.com&short_desc=bla&form_name=enter_bug&token=someToken
```

or more clean:

```
https://landfill.bugzilla.org/bugzilla-tip/post_bug.cgi
?Bugzilla_login=mymail@hotmail.com
&Bugzilla_password=password
&product=WorldControl
&version=1.0
&component=WeatherControl
&rep_platform=All
&op_sys=All
&priority=P2
&bug_severity=normal
&target_milestone=World%202.0
&bug_status=CONFIRMED
&assigned_to=somemail@hotmail.com
&short_desc=bla
&form_name=enter_bug
&token=someToken
```

And the response page says:
you have no valid token for the create_bug action while processing the 'post_bug.cgi' script

Why?? My token is great.

Comment: your token is someToken? (last param in your URL)

Comment: @JuriGlass Of course not. It's some numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the parameters shouldn't be in the URL. This isn't GET method.